# Configuring Kile to use a build folder with bibtex/biber

Tags: bibtex, biber, kile

I am looking for a way to configure Kile to compile all files within a `build/` folder (to avoid having all build files making a mess in the root folder).

I successfully did this for XeLaTeX using `-output-directory=build` and setting "Relative dir." to "build".

However, doing the same for biber, with the addition of `-input-directory=build`, does not work (it still looks for the aux file in the root folder).

EDIT: also, as was remarked, funnily enough Kile is complaining `[Biber] The files whatever.aux does not exist`

Comment: If at all possible, try not to use a "build" folder if you use LaTeX together with external tools. It is usually much more tricky to get right than to accept the few temporary files hanging around.

Comment: That said, Biber does not look for the `.aux` file at all. It looks for the `.bcf` file. According to the documentation it will take the `--input-directory` option (with two dashes, not sure if that matters on your system) into account. Check where LaTeX actually places the `.bcf` and make sure that that path is the one you pass to `--input-directory`.

Comment: Worked fine with TexMaker, though, don't know why Kile is making it so complicated.
I'm not yet ready to tolerate random files in the dir.
And it actually says "[Biber] The files whatever.aux does not exist"... :(

Comment: The message you quote does not sound like a message that comes directly from Biber. And as I said, it absolutely does not care about the `.aux` file. I just run Biber on a project where I had removed the `.aux` file and everything still went smoothly. Biber only cares about the `.bcf` file. BibTeX, on the other hand, works with the `.aux` file. Check what Biber's actual log file says (i.e. check the `.blg` file).